# ERROR: Invalid domain for site key reCaptcha

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, recaptcha

I registered my domain and added the key but want to test the site on my local machine. I publish the project on my machine to wwwroot and at the moment it runs on port number 8080.

I get the error `ERROR: Invalid domain for site key reCaptcha` when trying to run it on my local machine.

Is there a way testing this on the local machine?

Comment: By default, all keys work on "localhost" (or "127.0.0.1"), so you can always develop and test on your local machine. (reCaptcha version 1 - documentation). Probably this statement is valid for reCaptcha version 2 too.

Comment: You may need to reset your reCaptcha keys. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Check your domains at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin, if you are using localhost you most set your domain to "localhost".